# RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED error when making requests to the Google Assistant API

Tags: grpc, google-assistant-sdk

After some time playing with the Google Assistant SDK, I start getting this error:

```
grpc._channel._Rendezvous: <_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with 
(StatusCode.RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED, Insufficient tokens for quota 
'ConverseGroup' and limit 'DailyLimit' of service 
'embeddedassistant.googleapis.com' for consumer 'project_number:
<REDACTED>'.)>
```

What does this mean and how can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google Assistant SDK is free to use but has some [daily usage limits per account](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/overview#developer_preview_and_roadmap), to prevent abusive use of the API (e.g. non personal or non developmental use, as allowed by the [terms of service](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/terms-of-service)).

This trace is the error you get when hitting that limit.

The most immediate solution to this problem, is to try again the next day. If you need more requests for your project, you can also reach out to this [form to request more quota](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/support#additional_quota_request) explaining what your project is about and why you need it.